# Yup Validation for Formik Form - Issues with Validating Payment Date and Conditional Fields

Tags: validation, formik, yup

I'm working on a Formik form with Yup validation, and I'm encountering some issues with validating the pensionPaymentDate field and managing conditional fields based on the pensionAmountField and automaticIncreaseField. Here's my current validation schema:

```
pensionPaymentDate: Yup.string() //This is should always be required and be a valid range and not maxed
  .required('Required')
  .pensionPaymentDateRange('Enter a date in the current or next financial year')
  .pensionPaymentMaxedForFY(
    'You have received the maximum pension payment for this financial year. Please select a date in the new financial year',
    haveReachedMax
  ),
pensionAmountField: Yup.string().required('Required'), //If any field here is selected except Nominate then the form would be valid with this and the valid date range
nominationPeriod: Yup.string() //This would be required if nominate is selected
  .oneOf(Object.values(NominationPeriod))
  .when('pensionAmountField', {
    is: PensionAmount.Nominate,
    then: (schema) => schema.required('Required'),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired()
  }),

//This is then required if nominate is selected
nominatedAmountValue: Yup.number().when('pensionAmountField', {
  is: PensionAmount.Nominate,
  then: (schema) => schema.min(+min).max(+max).required('Required'),
  otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired()
}),

// required if nominate is selected
amountTypeField: Yup.string().required('Required'),

//required but up to this point if any option except for 'nominated (not nominate new field)' is selected here the form would be valid
automaticIncreaseField: Yup.string().required('Required'),

// if nominated is selected the below field is required
    nominatedIncreaseValue: Yup.number().when('automaticIncreaseField', {
      is: 'Nominated',
      then: (schema) => schema.min(0).max(100).required('Required'),
      otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired()
    }),
```

I also have some utility functions and additional code that are relevant to the validation logic:

```
// Utility functions
export const checkIfMaxPaymentReached = (pensionClass, totalPaidPayments, maximum) => {
  // ...
};

export const isValidPaymentDateAndNotMaxedForFY = (value, haveReachedMax) => {
  // ...
};

export const isValidPaymentMaxedForThisFY = (date, haveReachedMax) => {
  // ...
};

export const isValidPaymentDateRange = (date) => {
  // ...
};

// Module extension for Yup
declare module 'yup' {
  interface StringSchema {
    pensionPaymentDateRange(errorMessage: string): StringSchema
    pensionPaymentMaxedForFY(errorMessage: string, haveReachedMax: boolean): StringSchema
  }
}

export var string: StringSchemaConstructor
```

I want to use Formik's isValid function to enable a submit button when the form is valid. However, I'm facing issues with the conditional validation and making sure the form behaves as expected based on the selected options.

I would appreciate any guidance and suggestions on how to correctly implement this validation and ensure that the form is valid when the conditions are met. Thank you in advance for your help!